# PM2 breaks child process bash script

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, pm2

I have a place in my code where I need to spawn a bash script, write to its standard input, and read from its standard output.

I do this using node's `child_process.spawn`.

Unfortunately, when I run this code under `pm2`, the bash script hangs forever when calling `mkdir`.

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

**test.js**

```
'use strict';

const child_process = require('child_process');

setInterval(() => {
    const process = child_process.spawn('./test.sh');
    process.on('exit', () => {
        console.log('process exit');
    });
    process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Output: ' + data.toString('utf8'));
    });
}, 1000);
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMP=$(mktemp -d);
echo "Created directory $TEMP"
rm -rf ${TEMP}
echo "Deleted directory $TEMP"
```

**Expected output**

```
Starting
Spawning test.sh
Output: Created directory /tmp/tmp.I6Buifdmlu

Output: Deleted directory /tmp/tmp.I6Buifdmlu

process exit
```

**Actual output**

```
[STREAMING] Now streaming realtime logs for [test] process
2|test     | Spawning test.sh
2|test     | Spawning test.sh
```

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Node: 4.7.3

PM2: 2.4.0

**NB: I have tested this on Mac OSX and there is no problem**

Comment: Please provide code to demonstrate what you've tried, as well as the results you've gotten.

Comment: seems to work ok for me if i paste your code and run on ubuntu 14.05, node 4.73 and pm2 2.4.0

Comment: sorry, i meant Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Probably the same problem - https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2714.